# Output: object@1b6d3586 java

Tags: java, string

I have a problem regarding that my program prints objects instead of string.

I have a class which is called constants.java

in it there is the following:

```
public interface constants
{
        String[] FIELD_NAMES =
            {
                "test1", "test2"
            };
}
```

In my main class i try to print these fields.

```
public void fillFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < plate.length; i++) {
            // Det her er noget quick-and-dirty-fusk:
            switch (i + 1) {
                // Andre felter:
                case 1:
                    plate[i] = new OtherField(Constants.FIELD_NAMES[i], i + 1);
                    break;

                default:
                 plate[i] = new OtherField(Constants.FIELD_NAMES[i], i + 1);
}
```

and this is the main String print out function:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    System.out.println(plate[current.getPos()]);)
   }
```

the getPos is a number generator(lets say between 1 and 2) and the current is a player index, and i have checked it, and it is working. but when i fx. land on "`otherField`" plate, i get an output like: `otherfield@1b6d3586`

I think its because i am printing the object instead of the string, but how can i solve this?

Comment: You're printing the *address* of the object since the default `toString` of `Object` is called because you didn't override it (Since each object has `toString()` method, the default displays the class name *representation*, then adds `@` sign and then the hashcode)

Comment: `switch (i+1)` why +1 ? Keep it simple and put `case 0`

Comment: I found another solution too, but thanks! Greatfull that you could help :-)

Comment: doh! Thanks! it's alot easier!

Answer (score 1):

You are printing an instance of `OtherField`. You must override `toString()` in this class if you wish it to print something more meaningful. Otherwise, it simply uses the default implementation of `Object::toString()` class.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.

I was printing the whole object, so thats why i got the error.

I had a `getName` method in my other class which was linket `Constants.FIELD_NAMES` which i used to print the specific String.

so i used the method: `plate[current.getPos()].getName()`

Thanks guys!